# minimum of $x^2+y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find minimum of the expression $$x^2+y^2$$ knowing that $x, y, a$ are real numbers ( $a$ fixed real number) so $$x^2-y^2+2xy=a.$$

My solution is: $$ x^2-y^2+2xy=a <=>(x+y)^2-2y^2=a<=>(x+y+y\sqrt{2})(x+y-y\sqrt{2})=a.$$

I wrote for $a$ nonzero :

$$x+y+y\sqrt{2}=t, x+y-y\sqrt{2}=\frac{a}{t}.$$

Solving this system we obtain:

$$x=\frac{(\sqrt{2}-1)t^2+(\sqrt{2}+1)a}{2t\sqrt{2}}, y= \frac{t^2-a}{2t\sqrt{2}}.$$

We calculated:

$$x^2+y^2=(\frac{(\sqrt{2}-1)t^2+(\sqrt{2}+1)a}{2t\sqrt{2}})^2+(\frac{t^2-a}{2t\sqrt{2}})^2=\cdots=\frac{(2-\sqrt{2})t^2}{4}+\frac{(2-\sqrt{2})a^2}{4t^2}\geq2\sqrt{\frac{4-2}{16}\cdot t^2\cdot\frac{a^2}{t^2}} =\frac{|a|}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Now I wonder if I thought well, if the result is correct.

What do you think?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: Can $x^2$ or $y^2$ be negative?

Comment: Wouldn't Lagrange minimization work here?

Comment: @medicu : It would be helpful for others if you write your solution not using lagrange multipliers... That would be great.. Please spend some time and write it down....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: As you wished I posted my solution remaking the question. Waiting your opinions.

Comment: @medicu : It seem to be alright for me! well done :)

Answer (score 5):

By [Lagrange Multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) : define

$$h(x,y,\lambda):=x^2+y^2+\lambda(x^2-y^2+2xy-a)$$

$$\begin{align*}h'_x&=2x+\lambda(2x+2y)=0\iff \lambda=-1-\frac yx\\
h'_y&=2y+\lambda(-2y+2x)=0\iff\lambda=1-\frac xy\\
h'_\lambda&=x^2-y^2+2xy-a=0\end{align*}$$

From the first two relations above we get

$$2=\frac xy-\frac yx=\frac{x^2-y^2}{xy}\iff x^2-y^2-2xy=0$$

and then $\;4xy=a\;$ ...and etc.

Comment: I admit, the method of Lagrange multipliers was non familiar. After several attempts, by the elemenary way, with simple calculations we found that the minimum that is$\frac{|a|}{\sqrt{2}}.$